# What is the URL parameter for setting number of rows in a standard list view?

Tags: list-view, urlhacking, url

By "standard list view", I mean the page you get when you enter the three-character object prefix after the Salesforce URL.  Normally, there is a **rowsperpage** parameter that lets you set the number of records on other standard salesforce pages, but it doesn't seem to be working for list views.  By default, I have 100 records displayed in one org, and 200 in another.  I'd like to show 500 records or more.

It would look something like this:
**https://cs8.salesforce.com/a7d?rowsperpage=500**

Answer (score 2):

Possible values for `RowsPerPage` are 10, 25, 50, 100, 200. You cannot set it to 500. See the following page from the [VisualForce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm?search_text=rows%20per%20page).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as a standard URL parameter (not a VF element attribute):   https://cs8.salesforce.com/a7d?RowsPerPage=50

Comment: If you look at the reference I pointed you to, RowsPerPage is actually supposed to be for enhanced list views, not for regular list view. I suspect you've been using an unsupported hack that may be disappearing.

Comment: this rowsperpage parameter works as a URL parameter in various places in Salesforce - apex classes/triggers/pages views, expanded related list views (all of which could be "enhanced list views", I don't know).  It just doesn't work on the standard list view, and the standard list view is the one I need the answer for.

Comment: It's not documented anyplace other than as an enhanced list param. I did find this @SFDCFox answer in this post about [URL Overrides](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008oO0IAI) that's nearly 2 years old. It's  been known for some time that many overrides will be going away at any time. This could be one of them. They also don't work in SF1